# Store in a file the status of application using Qsetting or an alternative

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a Pyqt application where I need to add the ability to upload and save files with a custom extension. Basically I have some custom widgets that I need to save the status. I also need to save a "string" with the results, so I can load it later.

I was seeing that the status of the widgets can be saved using [QSettings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html). But it seems that the use of QSettings is focused more on the configuration of the application.

Basically what I need is implement the ability to save and load a file like a common software.

Should I use QSettings or is there another alternative?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for something like [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) or [shelve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html).

Comment: What ***exactly*** do you mean by "status"? It is highly unlikely that there is a magic bullet solution that is going do it all for you. It makes no difference whether you use `QSettings` or some alternative. They all just write configuration data in various formats (e.g. ini files). It's entirely up to you to decide what gets stored.

Comment: I need to restore all the widgets to the values as they were saved. And if it is also possible to restore some results. For example, if I have a Spinbox with some value, restore this value. It is posible using external .ini files?

Comment: By the way, it is posible use QSettings with custom widgets that contains other widgets (QLineEdit, QComboBox, etc)?